# Pruning fields out of a file

Tags: text-processing, awk

Content of file a.txt

```
Event: "112506400","17","2016/07/13-15-25-59.00",,,,,,,,,,,"112506400","115101234","02:00:00","pc","abc","4194","file_nam","F",,,"LA
",,"jk","123",,,,,,,,,,
```

I need a file which doesn't have $20 ( file_name ) redirected to asort.txt . Is there any short command as currently I am using the below

```
cat a.txt | grep Event: |awk -F, '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","$7","$8","$9","$10","$11","$12","$13","$14","$15","$16","$17","$18","$19","$21","$22","$23","$24","$25","$26","$27","$28","$29","$30","$31","$32","$33","$34","$35","$36","$37}'> asort.txt
```

Comment: Could you please reformat your question with code tags? As it is now it is hard to read.

Comment: Probably easier with `cut` e.g.`cut -d, -f1-19,21- a.txt` or (with GNU) `cut -d, --complement -f20 a.txt`

Comment: `txr -e '(awk (:begin (set fs ",")) ((del [f 19])))`

Comment: `txr -e '(awk (:begin (set fs ",")) (t (del [f 19])))`  (If some records don't have 20 or more fields and must be printed, we need an always-true condition! `del` returns the prior value of the deleted place, which is `nil` if there is no `[f 19]`, and `nil` is Boolean false).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the cut command can do:

```
cat a.txt | cut -d "," -f 1-19,21-37
```

Thus you skip field #20, assuming the comma is the stable delimiter.

Comment: you could improve by passing file name directly to `cut` and no need to hard code final column number.. so something like `cut -d "," -f 1-19,21- a.txt` :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
grep Event: a.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$20=""; print}' > asort.txt
```

Comment: @don_crissti I Modified it to preserve FS

Comment: this leaves an extra `,` of the deleted column, which may or may not be what OP required... for ex: compare - `echo 'a,b,c,d' | cut -d, -f1,3-` to `echo 'a,b,c,d' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$2=""; print}'`

Comment: To do it "properly" in awk: `awk -F, -v OFS=, '{for (i=21; i<=NF; i++) $(i-1)=$i; NF--; print}'`

Comment: @glennjackman It works. You should put it as an answer.

Comment: I think `cut` is the better solution. Feel free to include it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

with `sed`

```
$ echo 'a,,b,c,d' | sed -E 's/^(([^,]*,){2})[^,]*,/\1/'
a,,c,d
$ echo 'a,,b,c,d' | sed -E 's/^(([^,]*,){3})[^,]*,/\1/'
a,,b,d
```

- `[^,]*,` zero or more non comma text followed by comma
- `{2}` or `{3}` preceding group two or three times, use column number to delete minus one

similar with `perl` except that we can reuse regex pattern

```
$ # (?2) refers to ([^,]*,)
$ echo 'a,,b,c,d' | perl -pe 's/^(([^,]*,){2})(?2)/$1/'
a,,c,d
$ echo 'a,,b,c,d' | perl -pe 's/^(([^,]*,){3})(?2)/$1/'
a,,b,d

$ # golfed with lookbehind
$ echo 'a,,b,c,d' | perl -pe 's/^([^,]*,){2}\K(?1)//'
a,,c,d
$ echo 'a,,b,c,d' | perl -pe 's/^([^,]*,){3}\K(?1)//'
a,,b,d
```